# Characterization of Martingale and Definition of Uniform Integrability

Tags: probability-theory, stochastic-processes, martingales, stopping-times, uniform-integrability

Let $M$ be progressively $\mathbb{F}$-adapted process, where index set is $[0,T]$. $(T<\infty)$

> **Claim** If $E[M_{\tau}] = E[M_0]$ for all stopping times $\tau \in \mathcal{T}(\mathbb{F})$, then $M$ is a martingale.
>  If $M$ is uniformly integrable, then converse is also true.

**Definition** Process $M$ is called uniformly integrable if
\begin{equation}
\lim_{R\to\infty} \sup_{\tau\in \mathcal{T}(\mathbb{F})} E\left[|M_{\tau}|,|M_\tau|>R\right] = 0
\end{equation}

**Question 1** What is the reason for taking supremum over stopping times? On the discrete setting, I have seen that u.i. is equivalent for $L^1$ convergence of $X_n \to X$ as $n\to\infty$. What is the characterization in this setting?

**Question 2** Is the claim true? To show the converse, I tried to start with decreasing discrete stopping times $\tau_n \to \tau$, but without right continuity I am not sure how to proceed.

Comment: About your question 1, look here :https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/403908/uniform-integrability-of-rvs , if you can show that the sigma algebra generated by sets of the form $\{|M_\tau|>R\}$ are generators of the sigma algebra $\mathcal{F}$ you are done sine $M_T\in L^1$ unless mistaken.